# Primefaces - tab key in dialog lost selection on p:selectOneRadio and p:selectBooleanCheckbox when there is a scrollbar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 7 and I have a dialog with multiple inputs.

[image]

When I am using the tab key to navigate, it is working on the first p:selectOneRadio and when it came to the second one in the form,

[image]

the dialog lost selection and all input are no longer visible.

[image]

When I press tab key again, the the inputs become visible again.

is anyone already faced this problem and has a solution ?

Thanks